# NPE at Progress Dialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, progressdialog

The progress dialog gives me NPE.The code works fine in an another app but when i incorporate it into mine i get an NPE at mProgress.hide

```
private void showDialog()
    {
        mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Thinking",
            "Waiting for Facebook", true);
    }

    private void hideDialog()
    {
        mProgress.hide();
    }
```

this is how I've initialized it;

```
private ProgressDialog mProgress;
```

Comment: post your `LogCat` report for NPE.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/8321qsvn9/

Answer (score 1):

No, you've only declared your ProgressDialog.  You haven't actually created an object yet.
You need to do something like this:

```
mProgress = new ProgressDialog(context);
```

Comment: no this didnt help i tried with
mProgress = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext);

Answer (score 0):

> i get an NPE at mProgress.hide

This initialization fails

```
 mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Thinking",
        "Waiting for Facebook", true);
```

Hence `mProgress` is null.

Make sure `this` refers to a valid context

> public static ProgressDialog show (Context context, CharSequence
>   title, CharSequence message, boolean indeterminate)

Comment: @AswinRk well what does `this` refer to in your case and post the stacktrace. no snap shots pls

Comment: @AswinRk you still get the same error coz i only pointed the mistake. need more info where do you have the code that you posted in a Activity class non Activity class a thread a service??

Comment: this refers my LoginActivity.java

Comment: @AswinRk then it should work i see no reason why it won't work excpet you call hidediloag before showdialog

Answer (score 0):

Check that `mProgress` isn't `null` before calling `mProgress.hide()`...So, update `hideDialog()` method as below...

```
private void hideDialog() {

    if (mProgress != null) {

        mProgress.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: this won't fix the actual problem

Comment: Why not? we all know, this line causing the NPE...so, ultimately, `mProgress` is the `null` and its causing that NPE. So, if `mProgress` is `null` then it won't call the `hide()` method then there have no possibility to cause the NPE. am I right?

Comment: the real problem why its is null is it is not initialized properly check it for null is a safety but does not solve the problem of initialization. its just avoiding

Comment: Yeah, for that safety I'm suggesting him to do that. May be he calling the `hide()` method even before calling the `showDialog()` method.